# Erro em soma na iteração de um array

Tags: ruby

Comecei no ruby esses dias e estou com uma dúvida. Estava fazendo os exercícios do HackerRank e em certo exercício era necessário fazer a soma do elementos do array, simples não? Sim. Porém o meu código em ruby apresentava mensagem de erro:

```
def sum(n, arr)
    sum = 0
    for i in (0..n) do
        sum += arr[i]
    end
    return sum
end
```

Erro:

> solution.rb:6:in `+': nil can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)
>       from solution.rb:6:in`block in simpleArraySum'
>       from solution.rb:5:in `each'
>       from solution.rb:5:in`simpleArraySum'
>       from solution.rb:15:in `'

Código equivalente em JavaScript:

```
const sum = function (n, arr) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de procurar um pouco a respeito vi que estava trocando a sintaxe, quando usado `(0..n)` com dois pontos significa que o `n` está incluso na iteração.

Neste caso deveria ter usado `(0...n)` para não incluí-lo.